# `modern-ui` to `windows-store-app`

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Currently [modern-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) is described as:

> Modern UI, officially named "Windows Store" apps, is how we refer to the new design language and style used in Windows 8 (and Windows Phones)

It's an obsolete term for Windows Store Apps and we have a tag for those: [windows-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-app)

> A Windows Store app is a program distributed through Microsoft's Windows Store.

I think we should make [modern-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) a synonym for [windows-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-app).

Of course with this [metro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/metro) and [metro-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/metro-ui), both of which are current synonyms for [modern-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) (and should be) will need to become synonyms for [windows-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-app).

Answer (score 1):

To me [windows-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-app) should be used to indicate problems with the Windows Store app and not be used as a descriptive term for apps that are bought on the Windows Store.

Using it to describe the apps that have been purchased or acquired from the store makes it just as bad as the meta-tag [application](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/application), it is a descriptive tag rather than a useful indication of what the problem is. If it is a problem with a specific program from the store then it should have *that* as a tag, it should only have [windows-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-app) when the problem is with its interaction with the Windows Store.

Personally, due to the general misuse of this tag I would recommend it for deletion.

Comment: [tag:windows-store] is used for problems pertaining to the store. [tag:windows-store-app] pertains problems with apps from the Windows Store. The second part of your post could be debated, but if you remove [tag:windows-store-app] you'd need to remove [tag:modern-ui], [tag:metro], and [tag:metro-ui].

Comment: Not if the problem pertains specifically to the modern-ui interface such as elements in the wrong place in all metro apps, or asking about specific features of the modern platform. They are (IMO) nearly useless to describe an app itself unless the problem is specifically with the Windows Store itself. If we keep the windows-store-app tag then surely all other questions should be retagged with windows-desktop-app?

Comment: @Insane think about it this way: if the only tag a question has is Windows-store-app then what does that tell you about the question? Is it any more useful than the `application` tag? Tags should be specific and used to narrow down the problem, not describe the wider world. If the question is so vague that stating it is a Windows-store-app actually helps matters then it has other more serious problems. Just my 2p, but if the community wants the tag then fine.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. So basically windows-store-app should be a synonym of windows-store or vice versa. then metro ui / modern ui should be redefined to pertain to the start menu interface with the tiles and etc. I just feel dumb retagging all those application questions to windows-store-app

Comment: @Insane - There is a difference, it might be minor, between `Windows Store Application` and an `(Universal ) Windows Store Application`.  One runs on Windows RT, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 the other runs on any platform based on Windows 10.  Likewise `Modern UI` is limited to Windows 8.0 based platforms.